# 301 redirect with masking on GoDaddy

Tags: 301-redirect, godaddy, masking

We are using GoDaddy platform to put meta tags. We have 200 domains name some for the brand; some are related to our product. We want to redirect (301) all of 200 domain names to our main one with meta tags. Is this action harmful to our main website?

I know that domain forward with masking is not a good idea in SEO but if I use 301 redirect with masking. Is it still bad masking? I assume that with 301 the redirect one is marked as the permanent redirect to the new one, so 301 with masking is harmful or not?

Comment: It's not harmful. It's also not going to gain you anything from an SEO perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a 301 redirect with masking.  If you choose masking, GoDaddy will use a frame set to show your domain in the page of your alternate domain.   Regardless of what type of redirect you choose, there will be no redirect.  There will only be frames when you choose "masking".

Redirects are only necessary for SEO when you are moving content from one domain to another.   If you have registered alternate domains that have never had a website on them, they don't have any SEO value to pass on to your new site.   In that case, the type of redirect doesn't really matter.   Even 301 redirects are not going to help your SEO.  Freshly registered alternate domains never help SEO, they only get type in traffic to those alternate domains to your site.   Feel free to choose the type of redirect that you think will be best for users.

If some of the domains that you have do have SEO value and back links you will want to choose 301 permanent redirects.   You shouldn't implement those redirects using GoDaddy.   GoDaddy has a long standing problem in their redirect implementation.  They don't show 301 redirects to search engine crawlers.  See [GoDaddy's 301 redirect/forwarding has some weird random middleman URL, kills link juice?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/109693/godaddys-301-redirect-forwarding-has-some-weird-random-middleman-url-kills-lin)   Choose a more reliable redirect service or implement the redirects yourself on your own web server.

Masking has usability problems.   There is almost never a case in which framed redirects are good for users.

- Masking dilutes your brand because users are going to see a variety of top level domains over your content rather than your preferred domain
- The URL at the top of the page doesn't change as users navigate your site with masking.   That prevents users from bookmarking, sharing, or linking to deep pages.

Comment: "There is no such thing as a 301 redirect with masking." - I totally agree. However, I do find the [GoDaddy help docs](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/manually-forward-or-mask-your-domain-or-subdomain-422) and apparent [GoDaddy control panel](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55050/domain-forwarding-godaddy-forward-only-forward-with-masking) quite perplexing in this regard as they seem to _imply_ that a "301 redirect _with_ Masking" is actually a thing?! Does the in-app help suggest otherwise?

Comment: The OP is also "using GoDaddy platform to put meta tags", which is obviously only relevant with the _masking_ (framed) option, so this may also be a fruitless task and not worth the effort?

Comment: GoDaddy's interface does seem to imply that you can have 301 redirects with masking, but it doesn't actually work that way.   I really wish they had better documentation, an intuitive interface, and ran a redirect service that worked.

Comment: I would assume that the OP wants meta tags for SEO, but having meta tags with a frame isn't a good SEO solution.   Google won't index masked or redirected domain names even if they have good meta tags.

Comment: I don't know have they changed it or not. Last year, some of our masking domains appeared on bings and yahoo. Although, all of them are not on the first page. I assume this method to help get some traffic. I might wrong because too many redirects with meta can be marked as duplicate content.

Comment: Yahoo and Bing may be able to index masked domains.  Google does not.  Google hasn't for many years.